# How to send complex data from an interface to an executable in C

Tags: c, user-interface, ipc

Looking for good way to send data that is complex from an interface to an executable. I find it so difficult to use options and arguments because the arguments are so many and are variable length.

```
struct filters{
struct inclusions{
    struct filename{
        int flag;
        int rg_count;
        struct letter_range{
            char l, u;
        }*l_rg;
        struct name_range{
            char *l, *u;
        }*n_rg;
        char *l_specf;
        int n_specf_count;
        char **n_specf;
    }fn;
    struct extension{
        int flag;c
        int rg_count;
        struct letter_range{
            char l, u;
        }*l_rg;
        struct name_range{
            char *l, *u;
        }*n_rg;
        char *l_specf;
        int e_specf_count;
        char **e_specf; 
    }fe;
    struct size{
        int flag;
        int rg_count;
        struct size_range{
            unsigned long lower;
            unsigned short int suffix_l;
            unsigned long upper;
            unsigned short int suffix_u;
        }*rg;
        struct specf{
            unsigned long specific;
            unsigned short int suffix_s;
        }*sp;

    }fs;
}in;
struct exclusions{

    struct filename{
        int flag;
        int rg_count;y
        struct letter_range{
            char l, u;
        }*l_rg;
        struct name_range{
            char *l, *u;
        }*n_rg;
        char *l_specf;
        int n_specf_count;      
        char **n_specf;                 
    }fn;
    struct extension{
        int flag;
        int rg_count;
        struct letter_range{
            char l, u;
        }*l_rg;
        struct name_range{
            char *l, *u;
        }*n_rg;
        char *l_specf;
        int e_specf_count;      
        char **e_specf;
    }fe;
}ex;
```

}fil;
}

Comment: what do you mean from interface?

Comment: look for [IPC](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipc&oq=ipc&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.401j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=inter+process+communication)

Comment: if you are on linux, the simplest solution would be names pipes. You'll have to have a rudimentary protocol however.

Comment: By interface l meant the graphical user interface.

Comment: you have to serailize/deserialize your data (f.e. DTA, XML or JSON)

Comment: `complex data` is too general. Be more specific. What do you mean? `srings`? Actual objects `class instances`?

Comment: The data is a struct containing embedded structs some of which contain pointers to other structs:

Comment: This means l have data on the heap

Comment: include that info in your question. You can [edit] your question

Comment: that you have data on the heap is irrelevant

Comment: there are 2 parts to your problem: first, as PeterMiehle said you have to serialize/deserialize your data (I would add boost serialization to his list) and then you have to pass the data. As I've said there are many solutions for IPC. I think we've given you the directions, the rest is up to you to document yourself, the subject is too broad.